# Changing the postcode Validation Mask

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using native magento zip validation where its form is as follows: `99999999`.

I wanted to change this validation mask, only added a "dash" to it, thus getting it this way: `99999-999`.

Comment: you want to add validation which allows dash(-). Right?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: and its for which country?

Comment: It's for Brazil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code for PHP regular expression.

```
<?php
$regex = "/^d{5}-?d{3}$/";
if (preg_match($regex, "99999-999")) {
    echo "Found a match!";
} else {
    echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
}
?>
```

You can test this code online http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: I did a new test and it worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: can you please upvote this answer @MatheusPortela